# Как парсить динамический сайт подгружаемый скриптами?

Tags: python, парсер, bs4

Необходимо написать парсер при помощи BS4 для сайта:
https://www.soccerstand.com/ru/match/UZQNJWWl/#match-summary/match-summary
и вытащить оттуда значения коэффициентов (1.73, 4.08, 4.92).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я так понимаю эти коэффициенты подгружаются динамически скриптами и BS4 их не видит. Подскажите, каким образом их всё же возможно получить?

Comment: Смотреть, какие конкретно действия выполняют скрипты, и пытаться повторить такие же действия в python-коде

Comment: Как вариант читайте про selenium

Comment: @andreymal а как узнать какой конкретно скрипт нужен и посредством каких действий поступает информация о коэффициентах?

Comment: Открыть и изучать мониторинг сети в браузерных инструментах разработчика

Comment: @andreymal Я нашёл запрос, по которому сайт получает данные о коэффициентах. (https://d.soccerstand.com/ru/x/feed/df_dos_1_UZQNJWWl_). Но при попытке перехода по этой ссылке вылазит ошибка 401 Unauthorized.

Comment: Значит скорее всего выполняется авторизация по каким-то HTTP-заголовкам (возможно кукам), которвые вам нужно в python-коде откуда-то получить аналогично тому, как это делают скрипты